# How to show a sheet with a NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do you show a sheet with a NavigationView in SwiftUI? This is what I tried, but it doesn't show the navigation bar.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var present = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                present = true
            } label: {
                Text("Show Sheet")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $present) {
            NavigationView {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.navigationTitle` modifier belongs to the *child* views of the `NavigationView`, so you need to move it inside the closure and on the `Text`, which in this case, is the child view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var present = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                present = true
            } label: {
                Text("Show Sheet")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $present) {
            NavigationView {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .navigationTitle("Title") // <-- Here
            }
        }
    }
}
```